# Linux - Sort a File based on key position with header and trailer

Tags: regex, linux, sorting, unix, grep

Below gives the list in a file (unsorted-file) that needs to be sorted in Linux, preferably in a single line linux command.

```
03123456789abcd
02987654321pqrs
02123456789mnop
03987654321stuv
04123456789ghjk
01000000000
99000000000
97000000000
98000000000
```

Required sorted file output:

```
01000000000
02123456789mnop
03123456789abcd
04123456789ghjk
02987654321pqrs
03987654321stuv
97000000000
98000000000
99000000000
```

Requirement:

- If first two char is 01 then it is the header
- If first two char is greater than 90 then they are trailers
- Sort order: position 3 - 11 and then position 1 - 2

I tried a simple sort command like

```
$sort unsorted-file > sorted-file.
```

The requirement 3 failed. Then I tried

```
$sort -k 1.3, 1.11 -k 1.2 unsorted-file > sorted-file
```

The trailer records made it to the top of the file because of all zeros from position 3.

The other options that I know is to strip out the headers and trailers; sort the file and merge the header and trailer files back. Is there a way to do in one linux (complex) command itself?

Thanks for your time.

-R-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
( grep '^01' unsorted-file
  grep -E -v '^(01|9)' unsorted-file | sort -k 1.3,1.11 -k 1.1
  grep '^9' unsorted-file ) > sorted-file
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar. I tweaked your commands to sort the trailer row as well.  `(grep '^01' unsorted-file
  grep -E -v '^(01|9)' unsorted-file | sort -k 1.3,1.11 -k 1.1
  grep '^9' unsorted-file | sort -k 1.2 ) > sorted-file`